# Python - if not condition returning None

Tags: python, if-statement

This is another question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028828/python-does-if-not-statement-implicitly-check-2-conditions?noredirect=1#comment69265422_41028828

I am trying to further clarify the concept with `if`statement using `not`.
My understanding is that `print secondFunction(True)` will return `True` since `randomFunction` will be called but the script is returning `None`. Please help!

```
    def randomFunction(value):
        if value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def secondFunction(v):
        if not randomFunction(v):
            return "minus it"

print secondFunction(True)
```

Comment: You're passing `True` into second function. The if statement says "if the return of randonFunction(True) is NOT `True`, return "minus it". Since there's no else, it returns nothing, so it prints `None`

Comment: @SterlingArcher that is exactly what I understand but I was told that the `randomFunction` will be executed implicitly

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with the fact that you're passing true, so it's returning true, and you're checking for not true

Comment: @SterlingArcher I was hoping to get more clarification on this as I was given a code like that to review. I thought I always had to put an `else` statement to check if it's true but I was told that the `randomFunction` will always be executed even without the `else` statement

Comment: @Young: `randomFunction` is always executed. That doesn't mean that `secondFunction` will automatically return what `randomFunction` returns. You've probably misunderstood what `return` does.

Comment: @Young: Well, yes. How else do you expect Python to know if it should enter the body of the `if` if it doesn't evaluate the condition?

Comment: @user2357112 so if I have a function that writes some texts to a file within my `randomFunction`, am I correct in saying that the the texts will always write to the file unless `v=False`?

Comment: @Young: No. It would depend on where in `randomFunction` the file writing happens.

Comment: @user2357112 Please correct me if I'm wrong. let's say `v` is `true` and under `randomFunction`,  `if value: writeFile()` The `writeFile` function will be invoked under this condition correct?

Comment: @user2357112 thanks so much. It is now crystal clear!

Answer (score 2):

"randomFunction" returns True to "secondFunction". At this point you have this "if" condition:

`if not (True):`

If it would be "True" condition was verified and "secondFunction" returns "minus it". In your example it will never enter inside the "if" condition. For this reason "secondFunction" will always return None result because it has became implicitly a procedure without a return.

I hope that was clearly to you.